# I'm trying to print product details with Display method() but it's not working. created Product class and trying to display by accessing from main

Tags: c#

I am trying to print product details by creating a class Product and a method Display() in Product class to display product details.

I created an array of Product and trying to save products in array and trying to display the products from array by using Display Method.

User should provide choice whether he wants to ADD PRODUCT , DISPLAY PRODUCT or EXIT

based on choice need to perform action.

```
 class Product
    {

        private static int m_intProductCounter = 0;       // Initially Making Product Count = 0



        public Product()                               // Constructor for class Product
        {
            m_intProductCounter++;                  // Whenever new object is created or Constructor is called Count Increases
        }



        public int ProductCount                         // Properity for Product Count
        {
            get { return m_intProductCounter; }
        }


        private int m_intProductid;               // Product Id Variable

        public int ProductId                      // properity for Product Id
        {
            get { return m_intProductid; }
            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                    m_intProductid = value;
                else
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Product Id! Please Check Product Id.");
            }
        }



        private string m_strProductName;            //  Product Name Variable

        public string ProductName                   //  Properity for Product Name
        {
            get { return m_strProductName; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length > 3)
                    m_strProductName = value;
                else
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Product Name! Please Check Product Name.");
            }
        }



        private DateTime m_dateManufacturedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;           // Product Manufactured date variable




        //private DateTime m_dateExpiryDate;

        public DateTime ExpiryDate                                      // Product Expiry Date Calculation
        {
            get { return m_dateManufacturedDate.AddYears(2); }
        }



        private int m_intProductQuantity;                  // Product Quantity variable

        public int ProductQnty
        {
            get { return m_intProductQuantity; }             // Properity for Product Quantity

            set
            {
                if (value > 0 && value <= 500)
                    m_intProductQuantity = value;
                else if (value < 0)
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Quantity! Product Quantity cannot be Less Than 0");
                else
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Quantity! Product Quantity Cannot be more than 500.");
            }
        }



        private decimal m_decProductPrice;                     // Product Price variable

        public decimal ProductPrice                         // Properity for Product Price
        {
            get { return m_decProductPrice; }
            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                    m_decProductPrice = value;
                else
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Producr Price! Product price Cannot Be less than 0");
            }
        }



        private decimal m_decDiscountPrice;                 // Product Discount variable

        public decimal Discount                             // Properity for Product Discount
        {
            get { return m_decDiscountPrice; }
            set
            {
                if (value <= 45 && value > 0)
                    m_decDiscountPrice = value;
                else if (value < 0)
                    throw new Exception("Product Discount can be either 0 or morethan that, but can't be zero.");
                else
                    throw new Exception("Product discount can't be more than 45");
            }
        }

        public string Display()                                                  // Displaying Product Details.
        {
            StringBuilder display = new StringBuilder();

            display.Append("Product ID = " + ProductId + "\n");
            display.Append("Product Name = " + ProductName + "\n");
            //disp.Append("Product Manufactured Date = " + );
            display.Append("Product Expiry Date = " + ExpiryDate + "\n");
            display.Append("Product Price Per 1 Quantity = " + ProductPrice + "\n");
            display.Append("Product Quantity = " + ProductQnty + "\n");
            display.Append("Product Discount per 1 Quantity= " + Discount + "\n");


            return display.ToString();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to ADD product.\n Enter 2 to Display Product. \n Enter 3 to Exit.");
                string Instruction = Console.ReadLine();
                Product[] products = new Product[3];

                switch (Instruction)
                {
                    case "1":
                        {
                            Product p1 = new Product();

                            Console.Write("Enter Producr Id : ");
                            p1.ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                            Console.Write("Enter Product Name : ");
                            p1.ProductName = Console.ReadLine();


                            Console.Write("Enter Product Quantity : ");
                            p1.ProductQnty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                            Console.Write("Enter Product Price : ");
                            p1.ProductPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());


                            Console.Write("Enter Product Discount in number without % symbol : ");
                            p1.Discount = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());


                            
                            products.Append(p1);


                            Console.WriteLine("\n \n \n" + "Product Added Succesfully \n " + "ThankYou.");

                            Console.WriteLine("Total Products Entered = " + p1.ProductCount);




                        }
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(products[0].Display());
                            break;
                        }
                }
                if (Instruction == "3")
                    break;
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Why you are using ```products.Append(p1);``` for adding element to your "products" array?

Comment: to insert p1 into the array,  if it is wrong suggest me what to use instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you are using array for products collection? And inside while you are always creating new array for products (inside while: **Product[] products = new Product[3];**)!

Use List or any dynamic collection in this case, change your main method to this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            var products = new List<Product>();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to ADD product.\n Enter 2 to Display Product. \n Enter 3 to Exit.");
                string Instruction = Console.ReadLine();
                

                switch (Instruction)
                {
                    case "1":
                        {
                            var p1 = new Product();

                            Console.Write("Enter Producr Id : ");
                            p1.ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                            Console.Write("Enter Product Name : ");
                            p1.ProductName = Console.ReadLine();


                            Console.Write("Enter Product Quantity : ");
                            p1.ProductQnty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                            Console.Write("Enter Product Price : ");
                            p1.ProductPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());


                            Console.Write("Enter Product Discount in number without % symbol : ");
                            p1.Discount = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());



                            products.Add(p1);


                            Console.WriteLine("\n \n \n" + "Product Added Succesfully \n " + "ThankYou.");

                            Console.WriteLine("Total Products Entered = " + p1.ProductCount);




                        }
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        {
                            foreach (var item in products)
                                Console.WriteLine(item.Display());
                            break;
                        }
                }
                if (Instruction == "3")
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked I replaced Product[] products = new Product[3]; above WHILE. I want to try with ARRAY instead of LIST.

Comment: and change your array to dynamic collection )